# What's the absolute minimum code that I need to create a dynamic block?

Tags: block-editor

I'm making a test case for a dynamic block; what's the absolute minimum code that I need to register a block? (so I don't need to run `create-block` (granted it takes only takes 5 minutes for me to run, then initialize a git repository, and commit it, if I need to share the test case..) I want some smaller and more svlete?
Can I do something smaller and more svelte than running create-block?

I haven't been able to find a page that lists the absolute bare minimum.

I know I need to have:

a `register_block_type` function in php that's hooked with `init` that includes:
name
(and an array with:
`render_callback`, `editor_style` and `style` (and these 2 might not be necessary?)

- a function for the render_callback
- a function that enqueues the stylesheet(s) for `editor_style` and `style` (wp_enqu

e.g.

```
function create_block_test_case() {
    register_block_type(
        'will/my_test_case_block',
        array(
            'name' => 'latest block',
            'render_callback' => 'my_callback',
            'style' => 'my_style'

        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_test_case' );
```

```
function my_callback() {
 return 'hi, world!' 
}

$style_css = 'style-index.css';
wp_register_style(
    'my_style',
    plugins_url( $style_css, __FILE__ ),
    array(),
    filemtime( "$dir/$style_css" )
);
```

What else do I need?

Do I need to also create a block.json even though the block registration is done through  php?

(I know for a static block; I'll need to enqueue an editor_script JS file, but for the sake of this question; I'm just concerned about a dynamic one)

Comment: There's an example in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/419083/3898. You don't have to use `block.json` if you don't want to.